# Best way to store certificates of multiple clients in mTLS endpoint of AWS API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

We are exposing an endpoint that enforces mTLS via API Gateway to multiple clients, and I was looking up if there are any best practices for storing the certificates of multiple clients? The only way I could find is by adding all the certificates in a single S3 bucket separated by Certificate Begin and Certificate End delimiters. Is there any other better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is just configuring Root CA in API GW, then You request CSR from Your customer, sign it with Your certificate, and that is it.

The only thing missing is figuring out which customer contacted our API. You could request certain values to be set as CN in customer certificate, and then create lambda in API GW to rewrite CN from certificate to a request header, and then based on http header Your application can identify sender.